# Is $F$ a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $F$ be the function $\mathbb R[x]$ to $\mathbb R$ by the rule $F(p(x)) = p(0)$.

Is $F$ a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb R[x]$ to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Well, what's the definition of ring homomorphism?

Comment: It's a surjective ring homomorphism. See example $5$ in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism) and change it to suit your purpose.

Comment: The definition is 1. $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$

2. $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$

Comment: @Roy: And is that true for your $F$ or not?

Comment: Indeed it does?

Answer (score 2):

The question boils down to how multiplication and addition of polynomials are defined. And those are defined *pointwise*: substituting any real number $r$ in place of the variable $x$ for polynomials $p$ and $q$, we have
$$(p+q)(r)\ =\ p(r)+q(r)\\ 
(p\cdot q)(r)\ =\ p(r)\cdot q(r)\,.$$
In particular these hold for $r=0$.

Comment: So $F$ indeed is a homomorphism?